# spliting a list and using for a paging effect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have the below list made from my database which will bring back `x` number results. I would like to split the result into list of 15 which will have `List<List<SubjectModel>>` split list model.
 I would like to know who I can do this, as there may not complete spilt as 15 as the final will have less. Also on MVC if I was to create a paging effect how can this be done by calling a diffent index of data to be loaded or will I have to go to the server each time. 
I presume that I will have to have a parial page within a page.

```
List<SubjectModel> model = new List<SubjectModel>();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Comment: I do not recommend mark this duplicate as the real answer here will be: Do not fetch all, then split, instead do a real paging

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use the .Skip() and .Take() LINQ methods in the following way:

```
.Skip(pageSize * pageNumber - 1).Take(pageSize)
```

I recommend do not fetch all, then split, instead do a real paging using the methods above. When using those methods against a real O/R mapper like Entity Framework, it will translate to your RDBMS's SQL.

You can use action method parameters in your controller to know what page was requested.  Your pageSize could be a constant or a configuration value.

You can start learn the whole concept by googling: [implement paging in asp.net mvc]

Comment: so when i use this method i will getting the current page adding one and passing it back to the server geting the next page. how would i set this up in the conroller.